# Disabling a widget using BooleanProperty() is not working

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to disable a Kivy button. To do so, I've created a BooleanProperty and I've set the disabled button property as that BooleanProperty. When I launch, the button is created properly with the value I've assigned it (False). However, when I update the BooleanProperty, nothing happens to the button. When I click, I know that the property is properly binded and changed, because a print function shows me that it is changed.

What could be the issue? I am using Kivy 1.10.0. I've only kept the relevant lines of code - I don't think I missed anything, but I added comments with regards to what works.

```
class LoginScreen(GridLayout):   
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.selection = SelectionScreen()
        self.add_widget(self.selection)
        self.selection.bind(buttonStatus=self.disableButton)


    def disableButton(self, instance, value):
        self.selection.buttonStatus = value
        print(self.selection.buttonStatus) # returns True when I press button

class SelectionScreen(GridLayout):
    buttonStatus = BooleanProperty()

    # button to disable
    self.buttonStatus = False  # putting True disables button at launch
    btn = Button(text='BTN',disabled=self.buttonStatus)
    btn.bind(on_press=self.btnFunction)
    self.add_widget(btn)

    def btnFunction(self, value=None):
        self.buttonStatus = True # this updates property but interface not affected
```

Comment: In which part to disable the button? I see that the property is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`btn = Button(text='BTN', disabled=self.buttonStatus)` doesn't bind `buttonStatus` property with the button's `disabled` property. To do that, you can use `bind` together with the [`setter`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.setter) method:

```
self.bind(buttonStatus=btn.setter("disabled"))
```

Example based on your code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MainWindow(GridLayout):
    buttonStatus = BooleanProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.buttonStatus = False
        btn = Button(text='BTN', disabled=self.buttonStatus)
        btn.bind(on_press=self.btnFunction)
        self.bind(buttonStatus=btn.setter("disabled"))
        self.add_widget(btn)

    def btnFunction(self, *args):
        self.buttonStatus = True

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```